# How to get the name of current program without the directory part?

Tags: rust

In Bash this would be `${0##*/}`.

```
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;

fn prog() -> String {
    let prog = env::args().next().unwrap();
    String::from(Path::new(&prog).file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", prog());
}
```

Is there a better way? (I particularly dislike those numerous `unwrap()`s.)

Comment: Instead of looking at argv[0] you might want to use `std::env::current_exe()`.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't care about *why* you can't get the program name, you can handle all the potential errors with a judicious mix of [`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) and [`and_then`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then). Additionally, return an `Option` to indicate possible failure:

```
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn prog() -> Option<String> {
    env::args().next()
        .as_ref()
        .map(Path::new)
        .and_then(Path::file_name)
        .and_then(OsStr::to_str)
        .map(String::from)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", prog());
}
```

---

If you wanted to follow [delnan's awesome suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848132/how-to-get-the-name-of-current-program-without-the-directory-part/36848555?noredirect=1#comment61269021_36848132) to use [`std::env::current_exe`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_exe.html) (which I just learned about!), replace `env::args().next()` with `env::current_exe().ok()`.

---

If you do want to know why you can't get the program name (and knowing why  is usually the first step to fixing a problem), then check out [ker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36859137/155423).

Comment: `functional-programming.txt`

Comment: I would expect `env::args().next()` never to fail.

Comment: But, according to [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html), it may:

> The first element is traditionally the path to the executable, but it can be set to arbitrary text, and may not even exist. This means this property should not be relied upon for security purposes.

Comment: @vvv and [the docs for `current_exe`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_exe.html) go on to add: *Some errors can include, but not be limited to, filesystem operations failing or general syscall failures.*

Answer (score 6):

You can also get rid of the unwraps and still report all error causes properly (instead of munching them into a "something failed" `None`). You aren't even required to specify the full paths to the conversion methods:

```
fn prog() -> Result<String, ProgError> {
    let path = try!(env::current_exe());
    let name = try!(path.file_name().ok_or(ProgError::NoFile));
    let s_name = try!(name.to_str().ok_or(ProgError::NotUtf8));
    Ok(s_name.to_owned())
}
```

Together with the future questionmark operator this can also be written as a single dot call chain:

```
fn prog() -> Result<String, ProgError> {
    Ok(env::current_exe()?
        .file_name().ok_or(ProgError::NoFile)?
        .to_str().ok_or(ProgError::NotUtf8)?
        .to_owned())
}
```

Of course this has the prerequisite of the `ProgError` type:

```
use std::io::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ProgError {
    NoFile,
    NotUtf8,
    Io(Error),
}

impl From<Error> for ProgError {
    fn from(err: Error) -> ProgError {
        ProgError::Io(err)
    }
}
```

[try it out on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=44b4d4cabea10deda533bfdcb39a6db5&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: FYI, there's the [quick-error crate](https://github.com/tailhook/quick-error) that provides a macro to construct these error types along with the `From` implementations. Quite nice.

Answer (score 6):

Just one more `Option` version :)

```rust
fn prog() -> Option<String> {
    std::env::current_exe()
        .ok()?
        .file_name()?
        .to_str()?
        .to_owned()
        .into()
}
```