# How to get only the directory portion of the current executable's path?

Tags: file, path, directory, rust

I want to read files from a config folder at the directory where the executable is located. I do that using the following functions:

```
use std::env;

// add part of path to te path gotten from fn get_exe_path();
fn get_file_path(path_to_file: &str) -> PathBuf {
    let final_path = match get_exe_path() {
        Ok(mut path) => {
            path.push(path_to_file);
            path
        }
        Err(err) => panic!("Path does not exists"),
    };
    final_path
}

// Get path to current executable
fn get_exe_path() -> Result<PathBuf, io::Error> {
    //std::env::current_exe()
    env::current_exe()
}
```

In my case, `get_exe_path()` will return `C:\Users\User\Documents\Rust\Hangman\target\debug\Hangman.exe`.

With `get_file_path("Config\test.txt")`, I want to append `Config\test.txt` To the above path. Then I get the following path to the file: `C:\Users\User\Documents\Rust\Hangman\target\debug\Hangman.exe\Config\test.txt`

The problem is that `std::env::current_exe()` will get the file name of the executable also and I do not need that. I only need the directory where it is located.

**Question**

The following the following function call should return `C:\Users\User\Documents\Rust\Hangman\target\debug\Config\test.txt`:

```
let path = get_file_path("Config\\test.txt");
```

How can I get the path from the current directory without the executable name like above example? Are there any other ways to do this than using `std::env::current_exe()`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`PathBuf::pop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.pop) is the mirror of `PathBuf::push`:

> Truncates `self` to `self.parent`.
>
> Returns `false` and does nothing if `self.file_name` is `None`. Otherwise,
>   returns `true`.

In your case:

```
use std::env;
use std::io;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn inner_main() -> io::Result<PathBuf> {
    let mut dir = env::current_exe()?;
    dir.pop();
    dir.push("Config");
    dir.push("test.txt");
    Ok(dir)
}

fn main() {
    let path = inner_main().expect("Couldn't");
    println!("{}", path.display());
}
```

There's also the possibility of using [`Path::parent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.parent):

> Returns the `Path` without its final component, if there is one.
>
> Returns `None` if the path terminates in a root or prefix.

In your case:

```
fn inner_main() -> io::Result<PathBuf> {
    let exe = env::current_exe()?;
    let dir = exe.parent().expect("Executable must be in some directory");
    let mut dir = dir.join("Config");
    dir.push("test.txt");
    Ok(dir)
}
```

See also:

- [How to get the name of current program without the directory part?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36848132/155423)

Comment: The docs for PathBuf::pop now say:

"Truncates self to self.parent.

Returns false and does nothing if self.parent is None. Otherwise, returns true."

This is different from what this answer has quoted (I guess from the old documentation) which says "does nothing if self.file_name is None"