# How to get `__dirname` like nodejs using rust

Tags: node.js, rust

I want to create a cli, which has an init feature, it will copy the template dir into user's workspace, maybe need to get the `__dirname` like nodejs.

I'm a rust beginner but familiar with nodejs.

Comment: See [Stack Overflow, "How to get only the directory portion of the current executable's path?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749360/how-to-get-only-the-directory-portion-of-the-current-executables-path).

Comment: It's a good idea to _describe_ the behavior you want, instead of assuming that everyone knows what `__dirname` does.