# use static files in poem webserver

Tags: rust, rust-poem

I'm trying to use [poem](https://crates.io/crates/poem)'s [static files](https://docs.rs/poem/1.2.53/poem/endpoint/struct.StaticFileEndpoint.html):

cargo.toml:

```
poem = { version = "1.2.53", features = ["websocket", "static-files"]}
```

main.rs (simplified):

```
use poem::{endpoint::StaticFileEndpoint, Route, Server, listener::TcpListener};
let app = Route::new().at("/", StaticFileEndpoint::new("index.html"));
Server::new(TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:3000"))
    .run(app)
    .await
```

This works when I use an absolute path to `index.html`, but not with a path relative to my project folder: the browser displays `not found`.

Do I have to use [rust-embed](https://crates.io/crates/rust-embed) to include the static file in the binary ?  How ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StaticFilesEndpoint.

```
use poem::{endpoint::StaticFilesEndpoint, Route};

let app = Route::new().nest(
    "/",
    StaticFilesEndpoint::new("/path/to/dir")
        .show_files_listing()
        .index_file("index.html"),
);
```

You are using `StaticFileEndpoint` which serves only the specific file in this case `index.html`.

`rust-embed` may be required if you are creating a portable binary but if you are using a tool like docker, you can keep the files in your git repo and copy them before running your container.

Learn more about [StaticFilesEndpoint](https://docs.rs/poem/1.2.53/poem/endpoint/struct.StaticFilesEndpoint.html).

Comment: Thanks !  It looks like `/path/to/dir` is an absolute path.  My question is about a relative path.  I'm not using docker.

Comment: This should help ie `current + relative` = `absolute` path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749360/how-to-get-only-the-directory-portion-of-the-current-executables-path