# Executable compiled in Rust encounters "No such file or directory" error when run globally

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have developed and compiled an application in Rust. The executable relies on a directory named data, which contains files necessary for the program to read data. To ensure easy execution, I copied both the compiled Rust executable and the data directory to the /opt/motivate/ directory. Additionally, I created a symbolic link for the executable in /usr/local/bin/motivate.

When I run the executable from its directory (e.g., /opt/motivate), using the command ./motivate, the program executes without issues. However, when attempting to run the executable globally (e.g., by opening a terminal and typing motivate), I encounter the following error:

```
$ motivate
Error reading file: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

It seems that the program is unable to locate or read the data files when run globally. To provide some context, I have added the necessary paths to my .bashrc file.

Here is a snippet of the code for my Rust file. As a newcomer to Rust, I welcome any feedback or suggestions for improving my code:

```
use rand::Rng;
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json::Value;
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Quote {
    quote: String,
    author: String,
}

fn main() {
    motivate();
}

fn motivate() {
    let rand_filename = gen_rand();
    let file_name = format!("./data/{}.json", rand_filename);

    let quotes_path = Path::new(&file_name);

    // Read file contents as a string
    let file_contents_result = fs::read_to_string(&quotes_path);

    // Check if reading the file was successful
    match file_contents_result {
        Ok(file_contents) => {
            let json_value: Value = serde_json::from_str(&file_contents).unwrap();
            get_quotes(json_value);
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("Error reading file: {}", err);
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights into why the program encounters this issue when run globally would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a folder named `data` in the current folder when you run globally?

Comment: Yes I copied the data folder in the same directory where the executable lies.

Comment: Not the directory where the executable lies, the _current_ directory when you run the program.

Comment: If you want to access files relative to the executable, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46749360/5397009) shows how to access the current executable path.

Comment: Not really. My idea is I want to be able to run the command say `motivate` anywhere within the system and enable it run my executable.

Comment: Interestingly – I've successfully resolved the issue and got my code working. However, a new challenge emerged. When retrieving the current executable directory, it functions correctly, but in development mode, it seems to fetch the executable from the 'target/debug' directory. In dev however, the `data` folder is located in the outer parent folder. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I would recommend taking a command-line option to specify a path to your quotes (`--quotes-dir=…`) that you can use in development mode, with a default of `CONFIG/motivate`, where `CONFIG` is a [standard cross-platform configuration directory](https://crates.io/crates/platform-dirs).